# PrimeFaces redirect after Glassfish Login

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish

I am trying to add PrimeFaces to my project. It is running on `Glassfish 3` with form-based authentication. I downloaded the jar and put into `WEB-INF/lib`. After logging in, I was shown a css file with the URL:

`localhost:8080/[webapp]/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-aristo`

This does not happen if I disable security check. Here is the login part in my web.xml.

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login.jsf</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/login.jsf?failed=true</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should exclude web resources from validation. Add for example `<url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>` in your `<security-constraint>` element. Do that for all web resources which don't need security checks (js, images, ...).

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem. Sorry I can't vote up. It says to vote requires at least 15 reputations. Still new to stackoverflow.

Comment: So if you are new, just check this as answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by the restricted pages being cached by the browser.

The container managed security will redirect to the last HTTP request which triggered the authentication check. In your case it's apparently the auto-included PrimeFaces theme CSS file. That can happen if the browser has loaded the to-be-authenticated page fully from the browser cache, while the browser has loaded the CSS file fully from the server side, or have tested the cache validity of the CSS file by a conditional GET request. The container managed security will then remember exactly this URL as redirect-after-successful-login URL.

You'd like to exclude the JSF resources (`<h:outputScript>`, `<h:outputStylesheet>` and `<h:graphicImage>` from authentication checks. You could do that by excluding the common URL pattern `/javax.faces.resource/*`.

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Allowed resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <!-- No Auth Contraint! -->
</security-constraint>
```

You **also** need to instruct the browser to *not* cache restricted pages to prevent the browser loading it from the cache (e.g. by pressing back button after logout). Map the following filter on the same URL pattern as the one of your `<security-constraint>`.

```
@WebFilter("/secured/*") // Use the same URL pattern as <security-constraint>
public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        if (!req.getRequestURI().startsWith(req.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) { // Skip JSF resources (CSS/JS/Images/etc)
            res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
            res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
            res.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Note that this also fixes the "back button" problem. So the enduser would also not see the restricted pages anymore when back button is pressed after signout/logout as would happen in your current setup.

Comment: Thanks, BalusC! It seems that my problem is a simpler one, although come to think about it, it feels weird that why the new added primefaces css file, instead of the existing ones, gets shown. Right now, we don't have a logout page. But I will keep your suggestion in mind.

Comment: True, but you'd still end up with restricted resources being accessible via browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you have the wrong url-pattern in your security constraints.

Have a look at this example for a working version.

http://blog.eisele.net/2011/01/jdbc-security-realm-and-form-based.html

Comment: It is a great post! However, our project here is sort of legacy one. Transferring to jdbc based security is a little bit late. Very useful information though.